# что делать с ,буквой, которая встречается один раз при декодировании RLE

Tags: python

Есть функция для декодирования, но она работает только с такими строками `A15B1A5`

```
def run_length_decoding(compressed_seq):
    seq = ''
    for i in range(0, len(compressed_seq)):
        if compressed_seq[i].isalpha():
            for j in range(int(compressed_seq[i + 1])):
                seq += compressed_seq[i]

    return (seq)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы она работала с такими: `A15BA5`, где после буквы, встречающейся один раз нет цифры 1

с условиями не получается:

```
...
if compressed_seq[i].isalpha() and compressed_seq[i+1].isdigit():
        for j in range(int(compressed_seq[i + 1])):
            seq += compressed_seq[i]
    elif (compressed_seq[i].isalpha() and compressed_seq[i+1].isalpha()):
        seq += compressed_seq[i]
...
```

Comment: что такое "одиночная буква"? у вас их три в строке.

Comment: @strawdog очевидно это `B`

Comment: исправил, буква после которой нет цифры, потому что она встречается один раз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша функция даже `А15` неправильно декодирует (будет только одна А а пятёрка уйдёт в небытие). Так что я не стал исправлять вашу и написал другую:

```
import re

def run_length_decoding(compressed_seq):
    return ''.join(symb*int(n) if n else symb for symb,n in re.findall(r'(.)(\d+)?', compressed_seq))
```

Или та же функция, если расписать её в вашем (более классическом многострочном) стиле:

```
def run_length_decoding(compressed_seq):
    seq = ''
    for symb,n in re.findall(r'(.)(\d+)?', compressed_seq):
        if n:
            for j in range(int(n)):  # вообще-то весь этот цикл можно заменить строчкой: seq += symb*int(n)
                seq += symb
        else:
            seq += symb
    return seq
```

Comment: если использовать регулярку, то еще можно так:  `re.sub(r'(.)(\d+)?', lambda x: x[1]*int(x[2] or 1),compressed_seq)`